# Using XSLT how can I get my output to repeat instead of only returning the first instance?

Tags: xslt

I'm working on an XSLT script to output an HTML table containing data from an XML file but my resulting document is only giving me the first set when I need each set.

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

  <!DOCTYPE map PUBLIC "-//KPE//DTD DITA KPE Map//EN" "kpe-map.dtd" []>
<map>
  <title><ph conref="../../titles/sec_s63_title_l1.dita#sec_s63_title_l1/topic_title"/></title>
  
  <topicref href="../questions/sec_question_00260_1.dita">
    <topicsubject keyref="sec_s63_los_1"/>
  </topicref>
  
  <topicref href="../questions/sec_question_00260_2.dita">
    <topicsubject keyref="sec_s63_los_1"/>
  </topicref>
  
  <topicref href="../questions/sec_question_00260_3.dita">
    <topicsubject keyref="sec_s63_los_1"/>
  </topicref> 
</map>
```

This is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html> 
            <body>
                <h2></h2>
                <table border="1">     
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="//topicref/@href"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="//topicref/topicsubject/@keyref"/></td>
                        </tr>                
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h2></h2>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <td>../questions/sec_question_00260_1.dita</td>
            <td>sec_s63_los_1</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

This is what I'm trying to get:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h2></h2>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <td>../questions/sec_question_00260_1.dita</td>
            <td>sec_s63_los_1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>../questions/sec_question_00260_2.dita</td>
            <td>sec_s63_los_1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>../questions/sec_question_00260_3.dita</td>
            <td>sec_s63_los_1</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Where is my script off? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something along the lines of

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html> 
        <body>
            <h2></h2>
            <table border="1">     
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>                
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="topicref">
    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="@href"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="topicsubject/@keyref"/></td>
     </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much!! One last question, is it possible to return the first value without the ```../questions``` so only ```sec_question_00260_3.dita``` displays?

Comment: @pantherfan, easy in XSLT/XPath 2.0 with e.g. `tokenize(@href, '/')[last()]`. But you seem to use XSLT 1.

Comment: Not very difficult in XSLT 1.0 either, esp. if the substring you want to remove is constant: `substring-after(@href, '../questions/')`

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/map">
        <html> 
            <body>
                <h2></h2>
                <table border="1">  
                    <xsl:for-each select="topicref">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="@href"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="topicsubject/@keyref"/></td>
                        </tr>                
                    </xsl:for-each>   
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See the [Repetition](http://%20https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#for-each) section in XSLT specification.